# Mule EE development without repousername and password

Tags: maven, mule

I am using maven in my mule project and I do not have mule ee repo username/ password.
Will I be able to do development with EE without having credentials or is there any work around.
I continuously get the error

```
Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:pom:3.8.3 from/to mule-ee-releases
 (https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/): Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mulestudio you can completely use mule EE version of runtime to development locally which wont expire (Mulestudio -> help->Install New Software -> Update site: http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/studio-runtimes/). In this case for deployment in to prod you should have EE license in server( since you have used EE component in mule flow).

In your case, its  maven development, you can download Jars from  Mule CE repo( Open source Mulesoft repository), Maven settings as below ( Note : Have to use CE components for mule dev)

```
<repositories>
 ...
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
    <name>MuleSoft Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
    <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

...

Refer : https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb

You can't use EE repo until you have a valid license.Contact Mulesoft support

https://developer.mulesoft.com/mulesoft-products-and-licensing

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/installing-an-enterprise-license